# How to count lines in two files

Tags: perl

I want to ask how to count lines in Perl.

Example:

file a.txt

```
ikhsan
faqih 
kamal 
jundi
iqbal
```

file b.txt

```
ikram
izzul
ibnu
qoyyim
```

The problem is how to count all lines in 2 file in Perl.

If I just want to read one file my code is:

here is my data.txt

```
a
b
c
d
```

My code

```
open (FILE, "data.txt") or die "Can't open file: $!";

my ($lines) = (0);
while (<FILE>) {
  $lines++;
  print $lines;
```

and if I execute : perl countlines.pl

```
C:\perl> perl countlines.pl
4
C:\perl>
```

My problem how to count all lines in 2 files?

Answer (score 2):

This works with any number of files

```
perl -lne 'END { print $. }' a.txt b.txt
```

How it works

With the -ln flags the perl is compiled as script like this:

```
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    sub END {
        print $.;
    }
    ;
}
```

This loops on all the files in the list of files given and doing nothing!

But there is a special perl variable `$.` that is a counter of the number of lines read

So at the end of the script, this is printed out, showing the total lines in the files

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the automatic form for `<>`:

```
$count++ while <>;
print $count;
```

Usage:

```
perl countlines.pl a.txt b.txt
```

If you want to do it manually, you can just repeat your process:

```
my ($lines) = (0);
open (FILEA, "a.txt") or die "Can't open file: $!";
while (<FILEA>) { $lines++; }
open (FILEB, "b.txt") or die "Can't open file: $!";
while (<FILEB>) { $lines++; }
```

Comment: How of i wanna print result in IRC?